# Unity freezes from time to time (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: unity, 14.04

Fresh install of unity, it freezes approximately every 2 minutes for 10 seconds or so. When it freezes I am only able to move the cursor and switch between shell and gui (ctrl-alt-f2).

Video configuration: Intel integrated video card (Dell Latitude e4310)

1. How to find out what causes the freezes?
2. How to fix this?